# Django NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_newlist.user_id

Tags: django

I have a model form to display a textbox for the listname and a image for the user to upload. I am wanting the username to be pulled from the current request. When I currently hit submit, I am getting an "NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_newlist.user_id". I did a little experiment and when I include the field for the user to select their username from a list of all the users, it submits the data with no issues. Obviously that would be a huge flaw if I allowed the user to select which account to submit the data to, but my issue is that the form isn't auto populating the username field with the current request. My second issue is, when I do select admin as a user, the list posts fine, but the image url doesn't attach itself to the submission.

## View

```
def control_panel(request, username):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if username == request.user.username:
        if request.user.is_authenticated():

            user = User.objects.get(username=username)

            lists = request.user.newlist_set.all()

            listitems = request.user.newlistitem_set.all()

            form = NewListForm(request.POST or None)

            if form.is_valid():
                save_it = form.save(commit = False)
                save_it.save();

            return render_to_response('controlpanel.html', {'form': form, 'lists': lists,'listitems':listitems,}, context)
        else:
            return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context)
    else:
        return render_to_response('controlpanel.html', {}, context)
```

## Form

```
class NewListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('list_name', 'picture')
        model = newlist
```

Answer (score 1):

## Fixing Image Not Posting

Needed to add enctype to template:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                        {{ form }}

</form>
```

## Populating User To Current User

Needed to just assign user for the entry to request.user

```
    form = NewListForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit = False)
        save_it.user = request.user
        save_it.save()
```